# Resource Exhausted Error on allocating tensor of sizes that I can fit in my computer

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am running a keras/tensorflow model with a custom loss function that creates some very large tensors. But when I run the code independently (while debugging), I can store these large tensors in my machine. However when training the model, I get a ResorceExhaustedError, complaining about tensors of the same shapes I did use during debugging.  When debugging I do use the GPU memory as well, without any issues.

Also, I got 4 GPUs in my machine, but when the ResourceExhaustedError appears, it only lists GPU:0, even though I am passing a list of 3 GPUs at the beginning of my script:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.visible_device_list= "0,1,2"
tf.keras.backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

This is the error message:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[45324,45324] and type 
float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

At the same time, I can create this tensor, which is many times larger than the one creating the problem:

```
<tf.Tensor 'ones_3:0' shape=(6949680, 6949680) dtype=float32>
```

Why am I having resource allocation problems when running the model, but not when running the loss function line by line? Especially if I am running this on 3 GPUs, each with 8 GB VRAM?

Comment: First off, the error only shows the tensor which caused the crash. There may be other tensors blocking memory already that are not shown. I suppose it shows GPU0 only for the same reason: This is where the problem occurred first. Also, the tensor in question (45k x 45k) already takes close to 8GB of memory. I highly doubt you created a tensor with 7,000,000**2 elements as this would require over 180 petabytes. Likely, it is a symbolic tensor only, with no actual content.

Comment: @xdurch0 all great points, thanks. In the denial I didn't even considered calculating memory resources (btw that tensor would be over 180 Terabytes right?  Irrelevant to the issue either way)

Comment: Since lots of memory is getting consumed, the first thing you can try is by reducing batch size, it will be a bit slower but it avoids memory issues. You can also check the progress of all the GPU and kill unnecessary tasks. You can also try decorating with `tf.function` for better performance.